# apt-get is "Unable to locate package [package-name]" after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.04

I installed Ubuntu 15.04, then I updated it and restarted. After that I can't install anything from terminal using

```
apt-get install [package-name]
```

any more.
For every package it says

```
Unable to locate package [package-name]
```

It happened right after I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, immediately after its installation.

Is there any solution other than formatting the drive and reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Please provide content from /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?  After installation the sources have been installed, but the packages lists aren't initialised until an updater program updates the sources list. If it still doesn't work, provide the output of what Christian asked. Please [edit] your question, don't post long output in the comments.

Comment: Actually, Software Updater popped up and I did it. I now notice, it was before updating too. And to mention it no third party softwares where installed too even i checked it...so no music and videos which I could install later on but not without apt-get working.
This is my sources.list
http://pastebin.com/cPpnxxUi
And nothing inside sources.list.d

Comment: I am sorry. The problem was that the SERVER of my region was down. Thats why I could not get any updates and install. I changed my Server from Softwares and Updates and it is done... hihi... :D

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the content of /var/lib/apt/lists directory:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then try to run again :

```
sudo apt-get update
```